# error C2653: 'Application' : is not a class or namespace name

Tags: c++-cli

When i run this program it says in this file there is error called   error C2653: 'Application' : is not a class or namespace name

```
 #include "MyForm.h"


using namespace std;

int main() {
public:
    static void main1() {
        // Starts the application.
        Application::Run(gcnew MyForm());
    }

}
```

Comment: Is that C++-CLI? And that's not an error when running the program, it's an error when compiling it.

Comment: Yes that what i meant :)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing `using namespace System::Windows::Forms;`.

Comment: That didn't solve the problem it just changed the error to; error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

Comment: On a second glance, your code, while being quite short, contains too many problems and looks like a random mix of lines from different parts of correct programs. You should throw it away and read some basic docs on C++/CLI.

Comment: Im not coding with CLI i just make visual c++ programs and their .cpp files conatain some errors sometimes.

Comment: OK, didn't solve his problem, but it solved mine. :)  +1